# How to replace characters in Char table in Java

Tags: java, arrays, char

I have an issue with my Java application.
It is Maze solver app with the input file.
I've managed to build char table

```
   private char[][] maze = null;
```

and it basically returns an array with imported elements. 
Once I'm printed this array to the console I see values in  the correct order

```
public void print() {
    for (int i=0; i<sizeI(); i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<sizeJ(); j++) {
            System.out.print(maze[i][j]);
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I would like to:

1. Replace in this `maze` table all `1` with `X`
2. Replace in this `maze` table all `0` with `C`
3. Set a value `S` in a specific position of a table `maze[1][3]`
4. Set a value `E` in a specific position of a table `maze[21][23]`

Can you please tell me what should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i=0; i<sizeI(); i++) 
{
  for (int j=0; j<sizeJ(); j++) 
  {
     if(maze[i][j]=='0')
          maze[i][j]='C';
     if(maze[i][j]=='1')
          maze[i][j]='X';
     if(i==1 && j==3)
          maze[i][j]='S';
     if(i==21 && j==23)
          maze[i][j]='E';
  }
}
```